# Cookies not sent on Windows Phone app, but cookies are sent with same code in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, .net, http, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a basic class that makes GET and POST requests using `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`.

I use my class to login to an API and then request data. In a Windows 8 "Metro" application, it works exactly as expected. On a Windows Phone 8 application, the login appears to succeed, but in the subsequent request for data, no cookies are sent and the server responds as if the client is not logged in.

Here is the class, this exact same code is used in the Windows 8 app and the Windows Phone app:

```
class Class1
    {
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        CookieCollection responseCookies = new CookieCollection();

        public async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string received;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        cookieJar = request.CookieContainer;
                        responseCookies = response.Cookies;
                        received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }

        public async Task<string> get(string path)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            return await httpRequest(request);
        }

        public async Task<string> post(string path, string postdata)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
            using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null))
            {
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return await httpRequest(request);
        }
    }
```

And the code to initiate the requests:

```
    var n = new Class1();
    await n.post("https://mydomain.com/api/login/", "username=myusername&password=mypassword");
    await n.get("https://mydomain.com/reader/feeds/");
```

The curious thing is that if I prefix the domain name with "www." it works in both the Windows Phone 8 app and the Windows 8 Metro app.

I think it has something to do with how the domain is handled. The cookie's domain is ".mydomain.com", and without the prefix it must think the cookie's do not belong to that domain. After some searching I found [a report of someone noticing a similar problem](http://blog.codeblack.nl/post/HttpWebRequest-HttpWebResponse-and-cookies.aspx).

What I do not understand is why this is treated differently in the Windows 8 app than the Windows Phone app, so that line-for-line identical code works on one platform but fails on another.

---

I have done some more digging into this.

The server code I used for this is in PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST["what"] == "set")
{
    setcookie("TestCookie",$_REQUEST["username"] . " " . $_REQUEST["password"], time()+3600*24, "/", "subd.mydomain.com");
}

if ($_GET["what"] == "get")
{
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Client code in C#:

```
    var n = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
            await n.get("http://subd.mydomain.com/?what=set&username=foo&password=bar");
            await n.get("http://subd.mydomain.com/?what=get");
```

Here is an example of a cookie response from the server

```
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=295612ca; Path=/;Domain=subd.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie: TestCookie=foo+bar; expires=Fri, 04-Jan-2013 17:19:25 GMT; path=/; domain=subd.mydomain.com
```

In the Windows 8 Store/Metro app, this is the result:

```
array(2) {
  ["ARRAffinity"]=>
  string(8) "295612ca"
  ["TestCookie"]=>
  string(7) "foo bar"
}
```

In the Windows Phone app, this is the result:

```
array(0){
}
```

The Windows Phone does not see any cookies when they are set this way.

I change how `TestCookie` is set, the result from the server now looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=295612ca;Path=/;Domain=subd.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie: TestCookie=foo+bar; expires=Fri, 04-Jan-2013 17:29:59 GMT; path=/
```

`TestCookie` now does not explicitly set a domain, ARRAffinity is unchanged.

The Windows 8 Store/Metro app now returns this:

```
array(2) {
  ["TestCookie"]=>
  string(7) "foo bar"
  ["ARRAffinity"]=>
  string(8) "295612ca"
}
```

The Windows Phone 8 app, returns this:

```
array(1) {
  ["TestCookie"]=>
  string(7) "foo bar"
}
```

The `ARRAffinity` cookie is not sent because it explicitly declares a domain.

If I assign some breakpoints and check the `CookieContainer` of the request, I have two entries in the `m_domainTable`

```
+       [0] {[.subd.mydomain.com, System.Net.PathList]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Net.PathList>
+       [1] {[subd.mydomain.com, System.Net.PathList]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Net.PathList>
```

The cookie that isn't sent, is in the `.subd.mydomain.com` container. This is the same on both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

However, if the cookie declares itself like this:

```
Set-Cookie: TestCookie=foo+bar; expires=Fri, 04-Jan-2013 17:19:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
```

It is correctly sent on Windows Phone 8.

In my original case, the server declares the cookie the same way regardless of if it is accessed via mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com; as ".mydomain.com", but Windows Phone 8 doesn't seem to think a cookie for ".mydomain.com" should be sent to "mydomain.com". This is problematic, as even if the server puts "subd.mydomain.com" as the domain, it is treated as having a preceding dot, and then doesn't work through no fault of its own. It seems it has to not send domain info with the cookie to have it treated correctly.

Comment: _"What I do not understand is why this is treated differently in the Windows 8 app than the Windows Phone app, so that line-for-line identical code works on one platform but fails on another."_ - that is basically said because your code states _what_ it wants to do, but in a sense not _how_. It's up to the runtime ([WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) or [CoreCRL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/30/announcing-the-release-of-the-net-framework-for-windows-phone-8.aspx)) it's running in how framework calls will be executed.

Comment: But if you can create a reproducible test case (ideally with some serverside code to generate the cookies triggering the issue), feel free to do so and perhaps someone can suggest a workaround and/or file a bug with MS.

Comment: I have added some more info/code. I am not sure how, if this is truly a bug in the framework, more people have not encountered it. It seems like it would affect a lot of apps.

Comment: You are going to have to use two different methods to do what you want.  You will be unlikely to find a method that works for both a Windows Phone 8 application and a Windows Store application since they are two entirely systems.

Comment: @Ramhound I have a method to do what I want, I prefix the domain name with "www" and I can do that on both platforms and it works the same. The issue is that shouldn't be necessary and there is no documentation (that I can find) suggesting that the behaviour of HttpWebRequest cookie-handling should be different from WP8 to Windows 8. The way WP8 handles cookies in this instance seems wrong, but I think it is more likely that it doesn't work because of something I have done wrong.

Comment: Sounds to me like the windows phone 8 has different security restrictions than Windows 8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue, the feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771651/cookiecontainer-subdomain-handling-issue-in-net-4-0).

Not much going on right now but it was filed relatively recently.  I can only recommend voting for this bug and periodically checking back for its status.  If you can't afford to wait then contact Microsoft Support for a possibly quicker follow-up.