# Cookies in Windows 8 WinJS

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, windows-8, winjs, internet-explorer-10

How can i enable for the IE10 store the cookies?

Some internet services (Facebook Dialogs for example) pass variables this way which you need to use them in further request, but IE10 dont allow cookies.

What i'm trying to do is login at facebook with "Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker", get the token, and then open the feed dialog... when i try to open the feed dialog, i receive an error, because the page have no cookies...

Comment: Both the Windows Store version and desktop version of IE10 support cookies.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about `WinRT` Applications written using `JavaScript/HTML/CSS` then you don't have the notion of cookies, because this is not IE10 but instead it's the `IE10 HTML rendering engine` - *Trident*, and `IE10 JS engine` - *Chakra*. You have `AppData` (**Local state, Temp state, Roaming state**) in `Windows Store Apps` which you can use to store any data you want. [Here's a guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx) how to access the Local State.

If the question is really about IE10 then I assure you IE10 supports cookies if the user has cookies enabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, it is about WinRT, but i think that the WinRT open a IE10 windows to make the auth login at the class "Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker" what i want, is to persist the session/cookies when i open this dialog...

Comment: It is actually not entirely IE10. It is just the same rendering and javascript engine.