# How access the HTTP Headers in Windows Phone using WinJS.xhr?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, winjs

I'm trying to access the HTTP Headers after using a WinJS.xhr.

I can get some headers using .getAllResponseHeaders function.
But I receive only a few headers:

- Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 20:35:44 GMT
- Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
- X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
- Content-Type: application/json
- X-Global-Transaction-ID: 4132445
- Transfer-Encoding: chunked

How I can get ALL the headers?

Answer (score 0):

This answer already was answered here: [Get HTTP-only cookie from Windows 8 JS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549432/get-http-only-cookie-from-windows-8-js-app)
I needed several headers that:

> the system handles the cookies automatically